# Ошибка при git pull origin master

Tags: git

Есть репозиторий. Пытаюсь на рабочей машинке в каталоге, куда накатываю файлы из репозитория командой git pull, выдает ошибку:
Есть сервер на котором работаю разработчики. Есть эталонное приложение, на которое потом устанавливаются хот.фиксы. Все изменения сохраняются в репозитории git. Потом оттуда эти изменения распространяются на сервер приложения с помощью команды git pull origin master раз в сутки. Столкнулся вот с такой ошибкой. Как можно можно избавиться от такой ошибки в будущем?

```
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 33 commits, and can be fast- 
forwarded.
 (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)Reporting/
ReportingDoc/
XSLT/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт? Вывод в конце - это обычная команда git status и в ней нет ошибок.

Comment: Прошу прощения ошибся.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо свернуть все в Stash и сделать `git reset --hard HEAD`, а потом `git pull origin master`.

Comment: Спасибо. Только потом еще обнаружил, что у меня индекс порушился видимо.  Попробую так сделать.